# Apparent arithmetic error in conversion to tinyint for one string only

Tags: t-sql

Have a table of string numbers where all values are '0.80 to '1.10'.
Conversion to a tinyint lookup index gives an arithmetic error for one value only... '1.06' and I cant see why.

```
select @@version
select 1.06 * 200
select convert(tinyint, 1.06 * 200)
select convert(real, '1.06') * 200
select convert(tinyint, convert(real, '1.06') * 200)
```

gives...

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP3-CU-GDR) (KB4535288) - 12.0.6372.1 (X64)
212.00
212
212
211
```

Comment: When I run the above I do not see an error. Is your code above a complete example that reproduces the problem on your PC?

Comment: Jeff, Yes is exact cut/past from SSMS. So you get 212 and not 211 for last conversion? What version SQL?

Comment: Hi jarrods, sorry I took you a little bit "too literally". I so get the same output results as you. I realize now that you meant the arithmetic was wrong whereas I was looking for a SQL error message. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a classical case of rounding errors.

Check this code:

```
declare @val float = convert(real, '1.06') * 200;
select @val; --211,999984741211
```

You might consider converting to `float` instead of `real`, but even then it might be possible that you get rounding errors.

You might consider converting to `decimal` or `numeric`, since those types behave somewhat differently regarding rounding. But those types use more memory and are slower than `real` and `float`.

And perhaps you might also want to check if rounding functions (like [`ROUND`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql) and [`FLOOR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/floor-transact-sql)) might be useful for you.

From a design perspective, it would almost always be a better choice to store numerical data in numerical types instead of strings. (Numerical data is intended to be used for the purpose of performing calculations. Besides that, converting a numeric value to a string is technically easier and more flexible than converting a string to a numerical value.)

It's up to you to investigate these (and other?) possible solutions and then choose which solution would be a good fit for your issue at hand.

Comment: We thought of decimal/numeric at the same time.  Yes nomally I would have these values not stored as strings but the system they come from they actually come as '1#06' and I have to replace the # with a decimal point.

Comment: Yes. I see. The `decimal` and `numeric` datatypes have much larger precision than `real`. Personally I almost never use `real` and always with much reluctance. (I typically only use it when I need to store "raw" `real` values 1:1 in the database.) Anyway, choosing a correct and fitting numeric data type is sometimes a challenge by itself. I would suggest you learn more about the different numerical datatypes and the scenarios in which they are typically used. And going with a `decimal`/`numeric` type would generally be my first choice as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
select convert(tinyint, convert(decimal(3,2), '1.06') * 200)
select convert(tinyint, convert(real, '1.06000001') * 200)
```

both give correct 212.

I'll use decimal but confused why such a rounding error when only 2 decimal places used.

Comment: I think (but I'm not sure) that the conversion to real results in a value slightly less than 212 and that the result is not rounded but truncated when converted to tinyint.